# Replace special characters in string in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

How can I replace the string in Java?

E.g.,

```
String a = "adf�sdf";
```

How can I replace and avoid special characters?

Comment: Welcome to SO, zahir!  Where are you getting your strings from?  Random users?  A web service?  Are you trying to replace something with that string, or use that string to replace something else?

Comment: It looks like [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) - *"...the garbled text that is the result of text being decoded using an unintended character encoding."*

Answer (score 14):

You can get rid of all characters outside the [printable ASCII range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) using [`String#replaceAll()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) by replacing the pattern `[^\\x20-\\x7e]` with an empty string:

```
a = a.replaceAll("[^\\x20-\\x7e]", "");
```

But this actually doesn't *solve* your **actual** problem. It's more a workaround. With the given information it's hard to nail down the root cause of this problem, but reading either of those articles must help a lot:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)
- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: Hmm, there seems to be a markdown bug (link 2 isn't correctly parsed), but I can't seem to locate/fix it?

Comment: @BalusC: Happens to me all the time (since I link to the Java6 docs a lot), you want to replace the space near the end with `%20`.

Comment: @T.J. yes, that was it, thanks :) BTW: Firefox normally escapes them before pasting, but it didn't happen correctly for some odd reason. I re-created the link and the problem went away.

Comment: @BalusC: I find very ironic that you point out a Joel article... His first article on Unicode was full of errors and misunderstanding: I remember him posting it and thinking "WTF!?". It was a "ah ah I got it" memorable moment from Joel, that was *full* of errors. It's actually since he posted his first article on Unicode that I started taking *everything* he ever said and keeps saying with a huge grain of salt ;)

Comment: @Wiz: That was also one of the reasons I wrote another one myself to clarify the one and other more, even in simple terms and with practical examples and solutions. But.. It are really not that *much* errors in Joel's article as you seem to insinuate?

Comment: The only significant errors I see are (1) he says UTF-8 uses up to six bytes per character (which was true when he wrote the article, but was changed a month later), and (2) he implies that UTF-16 and UCS-2 are equivalent (which was never true).

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to answer the question without knowing more of the context.

In general you might have an encoding problem. See **[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer (...) Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)** for an overview about character encodings.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to remove all special characters, you can use the character class [`\p{Cntrl}`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Then you only need to use the following code:

```
stringWithSpecialCharcters.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", replacement);
```

Comment: That works if you assume "special characters" means ASCII control characters.  In my experience it usually means punctuation, but in this case it's anyone's guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Unicode escape sequences (such as `\u201c` [an opening curly quote]) to "avoid" characters that can't be directly used in your source file encoding (which defaults to the default encoding for your platform, but you can change it with the `-encoding` parameter to `javac`).

Comment: source file encoding defaults to the platform default encoding, i.e. usually not UTF-8.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks, fixed. I wasn't just inventing that, I wonder what language/environment it actually related to? ;-) Or was it true in 1996 or something...

Comment: I doubt that, since UTF-8 wasn't specified until 1993, and Java instead used to have the recommendation to use native2ascii before distributing source code. I'd expect UTF-8 to be the default in some newer systems, though.

Comment: @Michael: 1993 is earlier than 1996, and I remember it being all nifty and cool that Java supported these weird Unicode things, so it's *possible*, though not likely. ;-) (`native2ascii`, crikey, that's a blast from the past) Thanks, though, the info pre-edit was clearly wrong in 2010 regardless!