# How do I match unicode characters in Java

Tags: java, regex, unicode

I m trying to match unicode characters in Java.

Input String: `informa`

String to match : `informátion`

So far I ve tried this:

```
Pattern p= Pattern.compile("informa[\u0000-\uffff].*", (Pattern.UNICODE_CASE|Pattern.CANON_EQ|Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE));
    String s = "informátion";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if(m.matches()){
        System.out.println("Match!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("No match");
    }
```

It comes out as "No match". Any ideas?

Comment: How about `îñfórmåtìön`? Should it "Match!"?

Comment: Yes, that would be the idea. For now just the á would do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The term "Unicode characters" is not specific enough. It would match *every* character which is in the Unicode range, thus also "normal" characters. This term is however very often used when one *actually* means "characters which are not in the [printable ASCII range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters)".

In regex terms that would be `[^\x20-\x7E]`.

```
boolean containsNonPrintableASCIIChars = string.matches(".*[^\\x20-\\x7E].*");
```

Depending on what you'd like to do with this information, here are some useful follow-up answers:

- [Get rid of special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608205/replace-special-characters-in-string-in-java/2608252#2608252)
- [Get rid of diacritical marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397804/java-string-searching-ignoring-accents/2397830#2397830)

Comment: The java.text.Normalizer seems like the way to go(bullet 2). Unicode matching just doesnt seem to work as expected and I might be hit with a performance penalty even if it did.

Comment: If your *actual* functional requirement is "get rid of diacritical marks", then it's indeed the way to go. Your initial question was only not formulated like that :)

Comment: I think the question wasnt crystal clear. The goal was to be able to match "information" with "informátion", thus the ability to match 'a' with any forms of a like  'á','å' etc. Removing diacritical marks and then matching seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 7):

Is it because `informa` isn't a substring of `informátion` at all?

How would your code work if you removed the last `a` from `informa` in your regex?

Comment: informa\u0301 works in the pattern string. This has to do with the Pattern.CANON_EQ case.

Comment: Forgot to put in the link for this, http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html (Pattern.CANON_EQ)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to match letters while ignoring diacritical marks.  If that's right, then normalize your strings to NFD form, strip out the diacritical marks, and then do your search.

```
String normalized = java.text.Normalizer.normalize(textToSearch, java.text.Normalizer.Form.NFD);
String withoutDiacritical = normalized.replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
// Search code goes here...
```

To learn more about NFD:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normal_forms
- http://unicode.org/faq/normalization.html