# What is the better approach to trim unprintable characters from a string

Tags: java, android

I am reading data from xml. When I checked in eclipse console I found I am getting the whole data with some square boxes. **Example** If there is 123 in excel sheet i am getting 123 with some square boxes. I used `trim()` to avoid such things but didnot get success because trim() method trims only white spaces. But I found those characters have ASCII value -17, -20 .. **I dont want to trim only white spaces I want to trim those square boxes also**

**So I have used the following method to trim those characters and I got success.**

What is the more appropriate way of trimming a string

**Trimming a string**

```
String trimData(String accessNum){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        try{
            if((accessNum != null) && (accessNum.length()>0)){
//              Log.i("Settings", accessNum+"Access Number length....."+accessNum.length());
                accessNum = accessNum.trim();
                byte[] b = accessNum.getBytes();
                for(int i=0; i<b.length; i++){
                    System.out.println(i+"....."+b[i]);
                    if(b[i]>0){
                        sb.append((char)(b[i]));
                    }
                }
//              Log.i("Settigs", accessNum+"Trimming....");
            }}catch(Exception ex){

            }
            return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Edited***

use Normalizer (since java 6)

```
public static final Pattern DIACRITICS_AND_FRIENDS 
        = Pattern.compile("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}\\p{IsLm}\\p{IsSk}]+");


private static String stripDiacritics(String str) {
        str = Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        str = DIACRITICS_AND_FRIENDS.matcher(str).replaceAll("");
        return str;
}
```

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453171/n-n-n-or-remove-diacritical-marks-from-unicode-char) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122170/java-change-aeou-to-aeouu/4122207#4122207) are complete solution.

And if you only want to remove all non printable characters from a string, use

```
rawString.replaceAll("[^\\x20-\\x7e]", "")
```

Ref : [replace special characters in string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608205/replace-special-characters-in-string-in-java) and [How to remove high-ASCII characters from string like ®, ©, ™ in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008422/how-to-remove-high-ascii-characters-from-string-like-in-java)

Comment: I donot want to trim braces. its squre boxes not braces

Comment: Square boxes? Do You mean unprintable characters?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  str = (str == null) ? null :
     str.replaceAll("[^\\p{Print}\\p{Space}]", "").trim();
```