# string.equals not working for me

Tags: java, html, string, parsing, compare

This is the useful part of code:

```
java.util.List<Element> elems = src.getAllElements();
Iterator it = elems.iterator();
Element el;
String key,value,date="",place="";
String [] data;
int k=0;
Segment content;
String contentstr;
String classname;

while(it.hasNext()){

    el = (Element)it.next();

    if(el.getName().equals("span"))
    {

            classname=el.getAttributeValue("class");
        if(classname.equals("edit_body"))
        {
            //java.util.List<Element> elemsinner = el.getChildElements();
            //Iterator itinner = elemsinner.iterator();


            content=el.getContent();

            contentstr=content.toString();


            if(true)
            {


                System.out.println("Done!");

                System.out.println(classname);

                System.out.println(contentstr);


            }
       }
    }

}
```

No output. But if I remove the `if(classname.equals("edit_body"))` condition it does print (in one of the iterations):

```
Done!
edit_body
&quot;I honestly think it is better to be a failure at something you love than to be a success at something you hate.&quot;
```

Can't get the bug part... help!

I am using an external java library BTW for html parsing.

BTW there are two errors at the start of the output, which is there in both the cases, with or without if condition.:

```
Dec 20, 2012 11:53:11 AM net.htmlparser.jericho.LoggerProviderJava$JavaLogger error SEVERE: EndTag br at (r1992,c60,p94048) not recognised as type '/normal' because its name and closing delimiter are separated by characters other than white space 

Dec 20, 2012 11:53:11 AM net.htmlparser.jericho.LoggerProviderJava$JavaLogger error SEVERE: Encountered possible EndTag at (r1992,c60,p94048) whose content does not match a registered EndTagType
```

Hope that wont cause the error

Ok guys, Somebody explain me please! "edit_body".equals(el.getAttributeValue("class")) worked!!

Comment: Do a `System.out.println(el.getName())`

Comment: Its coming out to be span which it should be

Comment: you code is lacking key parts before we can even start helping.Does src.getAllElements(); actually output anything ? what is the API for Element#getName ? Assuming the equals on string doenst work is just so wrong, you really think that java would be still alive if the equals method on String was not working. In general when someone think the java API is broken then 99.999% of the times its not java but their own code.

Comment: Well, ofcourse `src.getAllElements` is giving output as iterator works perfectly if i remove the given `if` condition.. getName() gives you the name of the tag in string...http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/javadoc/index.html

And its obvious that I dont think that equals method is faulty or the JAVA API is broken, otherwise i wouldn't have asked for your help.. 

The title of the question is the closest phrase i could have given!

Comment: I've never had a problem with this but try converting both strings to the same charset? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.lang.String) Then compare array of bytes.

Comment: Ok guys!!!!!

Somebody explain me please!

`"edit_body".equals(el.getAttributeValue("class"))` worked!!

*BAZINGA!!*

Comment: if your string contains spaces in between words, i suggest you use compareTo() method, as it compares character by character

Answer (score 17):

I had right now the exactly same problem.

I success to solve it by using: `SomeStringVar.replaceAll("\\P{Print}","");`.

This command remove all the Unicode characters in the variant (characteres that you cant see- the strings look like equal, even they not really equal).

I use this command on each variant i needed in the equalization, and it works for me as well.

Comment: Perfect! It's what I'm missing for my code right now... Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Looks like you are having *leading* or *trailing*  *whitespaces* in your `classname`.

Try using this: -

```
if(classname.trim().equals("edit_body"))
```

This will trim any of those whitespaces at the ends.

Comment: @Arkanath.. Are you sure? Try replacing your `System.out.println(classname);` with: - `System.out.println("*" + classname + "*");` and see what you get. Of course first remove that `if`.

Comment: Unfortunately, Its coming out to be *edit_body* !...

The edit_body text got italicized due to the *s

Comment: @Arkanath.. Ah! Sorry. `*` made it italic I think. Replace `*` with `-`, and see whether the output you get is : - `- edit_body -`, with spaces or `-edit_body-` without spaces.

Comment: @Arkanath.. Well, now that's something strange. Please show use the HTML part that you are trying to parse. Only the part that contains that text.

Comment: BTW there are two errors at the start of the output, which is there in both the cases, with or without if condition.:

`Dec 20, 2012 11:53:11 AM net.htmlparser.jericho.LoggerProviderJava$JavaLogger error
SEVERE: EndTag br at (r1992,c60,p94048) not recognised as type '/normal' because its name and closing delimiter are separated by characters other than white space
Dec 20, 2012 11:53:11 AM net.htmlparser.jericho.LoggerProviderJava$JavaLogger error
SEVERE: Encountered possible EndTag at (r1992,c60,p94048) whose content does not match a registered EndTagType`

Hope that wont cause the error

Comment: The html part is

<a href="/quote/51597" class="black_link"><span class="edit_body" style="font-size:22px" id="51597">"He has all the virtues I dislike and none of the vices I admire."</span></a>

Comment: @Arkanath.. May be you are having some other unprintable unicode characters, that is preventing your string to match exactly. You can see this post: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772221/what-is-the-better-approach-to-trim-unprintable-characters-from-a-string  on how to remove the unprintable characters. I can only see this possible reason for this behaviour for now.

Comment: @Arkanath. You can also do: - `classname.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "");` before comparison.

Comment: @Downvoter.. Please Care to Comment, if you are downvoting any answer.

Comment: did both `classname.replaceAll("[^\\x20-\\x7e]", "")` and `classname.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "")`, NO HELP.. really freaking out :) Very strange!

Comment: @Arkanath.. I'm afraid man. But it seems like error is really somewhere else, which we can't solve by looking at your current code. You need to look at your HTML clearly. Probably validate it in some way. Because that is the only thing that might be causing problem here.

Comment: Yeah, that is what i am doing.. BTW link to the html is http://www.great-quotes.com/quotes/category/Funny/pg/1.. If you need!

Comment: @Arkanath.. That is a website? You mean the problem is with it's source?

Comment: As you know,I dont know where is the problem! I am just ruling out every possible mistake..

Comment: this is how i defined the source:
`String url_str = "http://www.great-quotes.com/quotes/category/Funny/pg/1";
            System.out.println(url_str);
            URL url = new URL(url_str);
            Source src = new Source(url);`

Comment: @Arkanath.. What?? Wow that is wierd. I mean this is really like breaking the rules. `s1.equals(s2)` should give the same result as `s2.equals(s1)`, if of course none of them is `null`. This is one of the contracts of `equals` method. I'm now more surprised as to what's the real problem.

Comment: Whatever the problem is, its a great sigh of relief, if you understand what it means!I've been at this since yesterday night!

Comment: @Arkanath.. Hmm. Well that is a positive point though. But, just to confirm, can you try: - `el.getAttributeValue("class").equals("edit_body")` and see if it works? I mean, it should work. It must work. There is no 2nd behaviour for this.

Comment: no dude its not working, it seems like some problem of encoding

Comment: @Arkanath.. Ah! Leave it. Just assume that you never faced this behaviour. Because this is unexpectable. Don't know why this is happening. Anyways, you got your job done. That's it.

Comment: hehe... yes i am leaving it for now.. but will look into this later.. interesting situation!

Comment: Excellent, But , the question is, Why I couldn't see those blankspaces or special characters?  ""- in this bracket there is nothing, So what is the wrong here ?

Comment: this is a complete solution, But SO likes the partial solution, sometimes complete solution is worthful and required. But stack overflow doesn't like this, this is unfair. I found this is a weakness of Stack overflow

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, `String.equals()` is NOT broken.  It works for *millions* of other programs / programmers.  This is NOT the cause of your problems (unless you or someone has deliberately modified ... and broken your Java installation ...)

So why can two apparently equal strings compare as unequal?

1. There could be leading or trailing whitespace characters in the string.
2. There could be non-printing characters in the string.
3. There could be pairs Unicode characters that *look* the same when you display them with a typical font, but in fact are not the same.  For instance the Greek code page contains characters that look by Latin vowels ... but are in fact different codes, and hence are not equal.  This is the [homograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homograph) problem, and in some scenarios it can be insidious.

One way to track down what is causing this is to write some debug code that does a `char` by `char` comparison of the result of calling `toCharArray` on the two strings.  Another way is to look at the respective characters arrays using a debugger.

Comment: DID I Say String.equals() is broken??I said its not working i.e. not working for me!!

Anyway, you explain me this:

`"edit_body".equals(el.getAttributeValue("class"))` worked!

Comment: It sounds like what would happen in my scenario #3.  Specifically, the version of your code that doesn't work has one of those "looks-like-a-Latin-letter-but-isn't" characters embedded in the source code.  Or maybe it is in the web page (though that seems unlikely given you got the new version of your code to work.)

Comment: Not working == broken.  Not working for me != not working.  There is not doubt in my mind that the String.equals method is working exactly as specified, and that the result you are getting is exactly as the specification says it should be.  The problem is in the way that you are using it.  You just need to be *forensic* in the way that you debug the problem.

Comment: yes thats the point, what happened in the new version?? I mean its surprising to me!

Comment: Please read what I've written ... I've explained (twice now!!) what appears to be the root cause.  I've no idea how you managed to get the "funky" character into your source code ...

Comment: I have understood your reason...

I just want to know that is there a difference between `a.equals("b")` and `"b".equals(a)`? Does `"b".equals(a)` removes the "funky" characters from a?

Comment: Nope.  The problem is the one of the string literals contains a funky character and the other doesn't.  You should be able to spot it if you look at the source file using some utility that will give you a hex dump of the characters.

Answer (score 0):

change the code to:

```
classname="edit_body"; //<- hardcode 

if(classname.equals("edit_body"))
```

if the code enters the if statement now, then there must obviously be some difference in the string content when you use the original "classname=el.getAttributeValue("class");".
in such case, loop over the individual characters and compare those to find the difference.

If the code still doesnt enter the if statement, either your code is not compiling and you are running old code, or your java installation is broken ;-)

OR.

if java is anything like .net (I don't know java)
is "el.getAttributeValue" typed as string?
if it is typed as object, then the if statement would not enter since those are two different instances of the same string.

Answer (score 0):

equals() is a method of String class. So, it works with double quotes.

```
 if(someString.equals("something")) ✓
 if(someString.equals('something')) ×
```

Comment: This is not the OP's problem.  `'something'` will give you a compilation error.  In the OP's case the code compiles and runs and gives an unexpected answer.