# Trying to support unicode in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, mysql-workbench

I am doing a project in which I have to save tweets into my MySQL database. The problem is some tweets contains smilies and other symbols which I am not able to save - it shows error like below :

> Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x82. ...' for column 'text' at
>   row 1

I was trying to convert to `utf8mb4` using [this link tutorial](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#character-sets), but in step 5, i have changed my.ini file in my **C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6** directory.

But when i do `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';` in my mysql console, i am not getting the desire result, my character set is not changed to `utf8mb4`, it is still `utf8`, please guide me how to resolve this, i am new to this. I have attached image to the step 5 (Modify connection, client, and server character sets) of the above tutorial.

[image]

Comment: Can you try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828910/php-error-description-incorrect-string-value-xf4t-l-xe9-on-insert) first?

Comment: thanks @Mjh it works, but now i don't need to change to `utf8mb4` , right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, you don't have to change to `utf8mb4`. I'm glad we sorted it! :)

Comment: @Mjh , it seems that it did not worked properly, after doing `ps.setString(3, new String(status.getText().getBytes("UTF-8")));` , it is inserting but for some text its showing text too long for my column

Comment: Well, UTF8 can use between 1 and 6 bytes per character. You need to adjust your column length to accommodate for the UTF8 strings.

Comment: thanks @Mjh, i had a column called tweets which is of varchar(140), when i changed to varchar(280), that error is not coming, but exactly how many varchar(?), should i put?

Comment: I don't know how many you might need.. you need to calculate that.

Answer (score 0):

Dup?  Need `SET NAMES utf8mb4;` after connecting.

Comment: where to set names `utf8mb4`

Answer (score 0):

[How to avoid Twitter emoticon character while processing string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214163/how-to-avoid-twitter-emoticon-character-while-processing-string-in-java)

I just found out, i don't want to save smiley and all, so i am just removing them `s = s.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7f-\\x80-\\xad]","")`