# Javascript: String.Replace

Tags: javascript, string, listbox, replace, special-characters

I'm trying to replace a special character (^) in javascript with string.replace but am not having much luck.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
var Temp;
Temp = lstRsns.options(i).text;

Temp = Temp.replace(/^/g, '\r\n');
Temp = Temp.replace(/'^'/g, '\r\n');
Temp = Temp.replace(/"^"/g, '\r\n');
Temp = Temp.replace(/^/g, "\r\n");
Temp = Temp.replace(/'^'/g, "\r\n");
Temp = Temp.replace(/"^"/g, "\r\n");
```

Any ideas? I get the text value from my listbox alright, it's just the darned ^ won't go away.

Thanks in advance for any/all help.

-Jason

Comment: Did you look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608205/replace-special-characters-in-string-in-java) thread?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a regexp meta character, and therefore needs to be escaped so it is treated as a literal:

```
Temp = Temp.replace(/\^/g, '\r\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to escape it with \ because it's a special character