# Java - Replace multiple characteres

Tags: java, string, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting Symbols, Accent Letters to English Alphabet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008802/converting-symbols-accent-letters-to-english-alphabet)

I'm not a Java programmer and I'm wanting to replace special characteres with non-special ones. What I'm doing is `myString.toLowerCase().replace('ã','a').replace('é','a').replace('é','e')...` but I'm sure there's gotta be a simpler way to do this.

I used to work with PHP and it has this [str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function

```
// Provides: You should eat pizza, beer, and ice cream every day
$phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
$healthy = array("fruits", "vegetables", "fiber");
$yummy   = array("pizza", "beer", "ice cream");

$newphrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);
```

Is there something like that in Java? Or at least something easier than using a `replace` to every single charactere I wanna replace.

Comment: You can use regular expressions for this: see answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608205/replace-special-characters-in-string-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think an equivalent of str_replace with arrays comes with the JDK, but you can easily create it yourself if you find it more convenient:

```
public static String strReplace(String[] from, String[] to, String s){
  for(int i=0; i<from.length; i++){
    s = s.replaceAll(from[i], to[i]);
  }
  return s;
}
```

Comment: From my understanding of the question, the OP is looking for a way to replace *special* characters, rather than any characters.

Comment: He said he would be interested in a equivalent of str_replace php function, so I showed how to easily create one.

Comment: Is it actually necessary to use replaceAll when looping over every single char? Isn´t replaceFirst enough?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Java for a long time, but you could always use an array of replacements (in any language)...

```
char[] specials = "ãéé".toCharArray();
char[] replacements = "aee";
for (int i = 0; i < specials.length; i++) {
    myString.replaceAll(specials[i], replacements[i]);
}
```