# Replace special character in a String

Tags: java, string, replace, str-replace

I have to replace a string whit special character like this: `XY_Universit�-WWWWW-ZZZZZ` in another one like: `XY_Universita-WWWWW-ZZZZZ`.

I tried solutions like `stringToReplace.replaceAll(".*Universit.*", "Universita");` but it replace all the string with the word ''Universita" and it isn't what i want.

Comment: Is that special character the only way Universit can end with, or do also have different uses? That is, do we have to confirm it's that character?

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace special characters in string in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608205/replace-special-characters-in-string-in-java)

Comment: How did you get the �? Maybe you should go back a few steps and get the real character.

Comment: i'm reading from file. The word is 'Università'.

Comment: To read a file, you must know the character set and encoding used. Usually, you would just know that it is the "platform default" and that programs adapt to that, whatever it is. If you get a file from another person or system, you have to have an agreement or specification. Then, you can use code like this `java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(java.nio.file.Paths.get("file.txt"), java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("Windows-1252"))`. Substitute in whatever encoding you know the file to be using.

Answer (score 1):

`stringToReplace.replaceAll("Universit[^a]", "Universita")`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String exp = "XY_Universit�-WWWWW-ZZZZZ";
        exp = exp.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s\\-_]", "");
        System.out.println(exp);
    }
```

**output**

```
XY_Universit-WWWWW-ZZZZZ
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to be *lazy* :P

use : `.*?XY_Universit.` to select only the first XY_universit

[demo here](http://regex101.com/r/zG2jD6/1)

Answer (score 1):

Another odd way..

```
String example = "XY_Universit�-WWWWW-ZZZZZ";
char ch = 65533; //find ascii of special char
System.out.println(example.replace(ch, 'a'));
```